# Distance of closest approach of a satellite after star explodes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

**Problem:**
A satellite is in a circular orbit about a star, when it explodes spherically symmetrically, to a large distance from the star and in negligible time.

The star loses 2% of its mass.

I want to calculate the closest and furthest distance of approach.

**My logic**: I can use energy to get $ \frac12mv^2 - \frac{GMm}{r}$ for the original orbit, then use the general orbit energy equation:

$ E = \frac12m (\frac {dr}{dt})^2 + \frac {L^2}{2mr^2} - \frac{GMm}{r}$

Equate the two, set $\frac{dr}{dt}$ = 0 at stationary (radially) points and then solve for min and max approach.

**My question is:** I'm not sure whether energy is conserved in this process, and whether I can therefore carry out this procedure. I am fairly sure that angular momentum has been conserved - as there has been no external force applied to the satellite.

Would I be able to use my method, even if angular momentum and energy are conserved?

Comment: What explodes?  The star or the satellite?   Closest and furthest approach of what to what?

Comment: @garyp I'm pretty sure Alderaan explodes, and the its the closest and farthest distance from Bermuda.

Comment: I must be stupid, then.  I still don't know what explodes, why the star loses 2% of its mass, and if something has been blown to bits, which piece of it are you interested in following for closest and furthest distance, and what you were trying to say in your comment.

Comment: @garyp A giant or super giant star can quickly blow off a non-trivial amount of mass at low enough densities that its planets are less affected by interactions with the gas than by the reduced mass inside their orbit. So despite the strange phrasing it's a question with actual application. But it is *also* homework-like under our usual definition.

Comment: I should note that I have deleted a couple of comments that violated our overarching "Be nice." policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system in its final state is created in periastron ($r$), so that's half the problem right there. To find apastron, use angular momentum conservation: $r'v' = rv$ and solve the energy balance equation for the maximum value of r.